# How to create an array with string elements?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to declare an array like this:

```
panel = ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'];
```

so that `panel(1) = A0`.

The problem is that it takes the complete thing as one element, like this: `A0A1A2A3A4A5`
with `panel(1) = A`, `panel(2) = 0`, and so on.

How can such an array be created?

Answer (score 2):

Using a cell array will generate the behavior you're expecting. You define a cell array using `{}` brackets, rather than `[]`, and access the elements using `{}` instead of `()`.

```
panel = {'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'};
disp(panel{1});
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use cell arrays as explained in [DMR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571810/5698672) or the following approaches:

1. Use multiple rows instead of a single row like this:

   ```
   panel = ['A0'; 'A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'; 'A4'; 'A5'];
   ```

   then `A0` can be accessed using: `panel(1,:)`, `A1` using `panel(2,:)`, ...

---

2. If you have MATLAB 2017a, you can create [string arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) like this:

   ```
   panel = ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"];
   ```

   and then `A0` can be accessed using: `panel(1)`, `A1` using `panel(2)`, ...